# Java 8: Generating String ID from Long

Tags: java, string, groovy, java-8

Below is the method I am using to generate a string reference id which is of length 12 and starts with 'X' and ends with the input `number` and the middle of String is filled with zeros

```
public String generateRefId(Long number){       
    int digits = 1 + (int)Math.floor(Math.log10(number));
    int length = 11 - digits;
    StringBuilder refid = new StringBuilder(12);
    refid.append('X');
    for(int i= length;i> 0;i--) {
    refid.append('0'); 
    }
    refid.append(number);

    Assert.assertEquals(refid.length(),12);
    return refid.toString();
}
```

Below are the usecases

```
Input           Output
12345       X00000012345
999999999   X00999999999
```

The above method works fine but Am wondering if the above method can be optimized further using java 8?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `String.format`.  E.g.

```
String.format("X%011d", 4366)
```

This pads the number with `0` on the left side.  But be aware, that larger numbers, will take more space.

```
groovy:000> String.format("X%011d", 4366)
===> X00000004366
groovy:000> String.format("X%011d", 111111111111)
===> X111111111111
```

Comment: And this has been available since Java 5.

Answer (score 3):

IFF guava is an option, this would be so much easier:

```
String input = "12345";
System.out.println("X" + Strings.padStart(input, 11, '0'));
```

Answer (score 2):

In Groovy, since 1.0:

```
'X' + input.padLeft(11, '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, apache-commons-lang provides the [`StringUtils.leftPad()` method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#leftPad-java.lang.String-int-char-) :

> ```
> public static String leftPad(final String str, final int size, final char padChar)
> ```

You could so write :

```
String input = "999999999";
String formatedValue = "X" + StringUtils.leftPad(input, 11, '0');
```